# @JsonInclude filtering by class' attribute

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson-dataformat-xml

I am working on serializing classes to XML. I've found `@JsonInclude` to be immensely helpful. However, I am having issues on filtering a class by its attribute. In the xml, if it's a US address I need to have one set of annotations for the fields using `@JsonProperty`. Because of this, I'm trying to use the `Include` annotation to only show the relevant field based on the country.

The US address needs to have `USAddress` as the wrapper element name. Foreign Addresses need to have `ForeignAddress` as the wrapper element name as well as different element names for state/zip.

Is there a way to access the class and it's attributes in the filter? I've tried using the super class for both types of addresses, but with Bazel, I run into circular dependency issues when doing that. Im super new to bazel :P

```java
public class Thing {
  @JsonInclude(value = Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = CountryFilter.class)
  private final USAddress usAddress = new USAddress({line1: "123 MockingBird Ln", country: "US"});
  @JsonInclude(value = Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = CountryFilter.class)
  private final ForeignAddress foreignAddress = new ForeignAddress({line1: "123 MockingBird Ln", country: "DE"});
}

public class CountryFilter {
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return ...; // This is where I'm having issues. Would like it to do something like obj.getCountry().equals("US").
  }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using the `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` and then used a conditional in the constructor to optionally set the address. But curious if there's a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) and then used a conditional in the constructor to optionally set the address.